# How to use data/file in Datasources/folder to make program portable

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently i have a program that uses a file (picture) from my PC. I found out i can load my picture into the program `DataSources` but this won't help me solving my problem. When I replace the program or transfer it to another PC and run, it crashes because of the second line:

```
InitializeComponent();
        Animation = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CourseWork\CourseWork\Properties\DataSources\Selection-Sort-Animation (1).gif");
```

I wonder how to set the path `(@"")` properly or do something else so my program can find and load a picture on any machine.

Comment: In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, you can select the file, then in the Properties panel set the build action for the image file to "Embedded Resource", which will make it get built into the executable.  Then retrieve it with [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @adv12 Could you please write the line how to retrieve it. I am stacked at line `System.Reflection.Assembly.` There is no option `GetManifestResourceStream` further to pick. And do i need to place it into the brackets like so: `new Bitmap(Assembly...)` ?

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan You can put your images and other resources in a `Resources.Resx` file and then use them simply like this: `this.PictureBox1.Image=Properties.Resources.Image1;` for example.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I just found that method but i have a little problem. Actually I have a `gif` picture and in this case it looks like a simple picture (not changing as gif is)

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan I also tested it using an animated gif and set it as `pictureBox1.Image` and it worked properly. To learn how to use resource files, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the image in a `Resources.resx` file.

- It supports Localization
- It is simple to maintain and use
- It has a good design-time support and you can use resource items later in designer; for example set the back ground image of the form to a resource item using designer.

When you create a Windows Forms Application, if you look in solution explorer, you will see a `Resources.resx` file exists in the `Properties` folder. you can use this file (or add another `.resx` file) to embed resources in your application to do so:

**Using Resource Designer:**

1. Open `Resoures.resx` designer.
2. Click on drop down of Add resource Button in toolbar of designer.
3. Click on Add Existing File ...
4. Browse and select the file you want and click Open.
5. The file will be added in `Resources.resx` with a name.
6. Also you can see the file in Resources folder of your project. These files will not copy to output and are here only for you to have simple access to change them in future.

**Accessing Resources:**

You can access each resource simply with its name, for example:

```
this.PictureBox1.Image= Properties.Resources.Loading;
```

Comment: This works. But using `pictureBox` I can't find a way to change the image resolution as I could change in Bitmap. My image is too big. Searching for a clue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I think to change a gif resolution you should do more work than changing the resolution of a bitmap because the gif has more frames.

Comment: Found an easy way, It is needed to set `SizeMode=StretchImage` in `pictureBox` properties and resize the pictureBox to a size you want it to be. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Great! Yes, it changes the size of image, I thought you really mean changing the resolution :)